# Surprising output of text manipulation when contains '#'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text

I have a string in python 2.7

```
s1='path#poss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
```

which I want to strip *'path#'*  from the beginning of it.
When I use **lstrip** it ends up in weird output with an extra **'p'** stripped. The output of

```
s2 = s1.lstrip('path#')
```

is

```
'oss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
```

instead of

```
'poss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
```

It works perfectly for other examples like:

```
'path#nsubj|<-nsubj<-leader->prep->of->pobj->|pobj'
```

which is stripped correctly to:

```
'nsubj|<-nsubj<-leader->prep->of->pobj->|pobj'
```

Why is python stripping the extra letter from the string?

Comment: `.lstrip(s)` removes all the characters in `s`; it does not remove the **string** `s`.  `"xxxxxxxxy".lstrip('x') == "y"`.

Comment: 1) It has nothing to do with '#'
2) 'strip' or 'lstrip' or 'rstrip' are removing characters not substrings. Input to these functions will be behaved like single characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
prefix_to_strip = 'path#'
s1 = 'path#poss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
s1 = s1[len(prefix_to_strip):]
```

`strip()` doesn't work because it just removes **any** character found in the string (or, iterable, strictly speaking) you pass to it.

**P.S.** If you want to be able to safely apply this to any string (i.e. string that might not start with `path#`), do this:

```
if s1.startswith(prefix_to_strip):
    s1 = s1[len(prefix_to_strip):]
```

or even:

```
def strip_prefix(prefix, string):
    return string[len(prefix):] if string.startswith(prefix) else string

strip_prefix('foo#', 'foo#bar')  # => 'bar'
strip_prefix('foo#', 'hello')  # => 'hello'
```

Comment: But why does the problem occur? It's interesting.

Comment: I got it. it removes any single 'p','a','t','h' and '#' from my string.

Comment: it removes any single p a t h # from the beginning until he finds something different, then stops

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from the documentation of [lstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars
>   argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

The characters you pass as an argument is a set, and since `'p'` is part of it, it will remove the `'p'` you are missing.

Answer (score 3):

This will explain everything I believe

```
s1 = 'pppppppppppppp1pppppppppppppp'
print s1.lstrip("path#")
print s1.rstrip("path#")
print s1.strip("path#")
```

**Output**

```
1pppppppppppppp
pppppppppppppp1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not weird. `str.strip` doesn't removes prefix or suffix, it removes all combinations of characters passed to it.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on `str.strip([chars])`:

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The `chars` argument is a string specifying the **set of
>   characters** to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument
>   defaults to removing whitespace. The **chars** argument is not a
>   **prefix** or **suffix**; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

And same thing is applicable to [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

**Fix:**

```
>>> s1 = 'path#poss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
if s1.startswith('path#'):
   s2 = s1[len('path#'):]
>>> s2
'poss|<-poss<-home->prep->in->pobj->|pobj'
```